# Node Express Render Dom Elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a League of Legends Account lookup website, and I am trying to learn how to render the HTML properly. I have a large object containing the information for many different matches in it. I want to create a DOM element for each match in the match History, and then populate that element with the information contained in the object. How can I do this in a dynamic fashion. I will not always know how many matches will be in the object.

```
 match0: {
    champion: 76,
    gameStartTime: 1600413655154,
    gameDuration: 1347,
    playerList: {
      Team_100_JUNGLE: [Object],
      Team_100_MIDDLE: [Object],
      Team_100_BOTTOM: [Object],
      Team_100_SUPPORT: [Object],
      Team_100_TOP: [Object],
      Team_200_MIDDLE: [Object],
      Team_200_JUNGLE: [Object],
      Team_200_BOTTOM: [Object],
      Team_200_SUPPORT: [Object],
      Team_200_TOP: [Object]
    },
    result: 'Loss',
    team_100_total_kills: 15,
    team_200_total_kills: 23
  },
```

This is what each match looks like inside the match History Array. There could be 1 of these objects in the array, or 1000. How can I do this? Do I need to completely restructure the way I am going about this? Send Help.

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion your best choise is to use somekind of templating engine, you can predefine a DOM Structure (template) then throw your Data Object (json at best) at it and it will render the template with all the data provided by your Data Object.

Handlebarsjs is my choise but there are a lot of alternatives, hope it helps if you need further help let me know
https://handlebarsjs.com/

EDIT: I sadly did not work with EJS but i try to explain it with an Handlebars example. The "matchhistory.hbs" is your example template which you could use to display all your matches. This happens through the #each it will loop through all your data that you provide it with. In the webserver you just have to render it and send it back to the user requesting https://example.com/matchhisorty for example.

As for your current problem you dont have create the DOM the rendner will do that for you.

Express webserver(index.js):

```js
//This is only temporary, you need to call the lol api so you got the newest data
//Call the api in the router.get('/matchhistory')

let matchhistory = [
match0: {
    champion: 76,
    ...
    result: 'Loss',
    team_100_total_kills: 15,
    team_200_total_kills: 23
  },
  match1: {
    champion: 76,
    ...
    result: 'Loss',
    team_100_total_kills: 15,
    team_200_total_kills: 23
  },
]


router.get('/matchhistory', function(req, res, next) {
  let raw = matchhistory; //Here you can make your api call to get the matchhistory data
  let parsedata = JSON.parse(raw); //Parse it to json
  res.render('matchhistory', { title: 'Posts - Canime', pod_cards: home.pod.cards , naventry: home.nav.naventry}); //Send back the rendered Page
});
```

matchhistory..hbs

```
<ul class="matchhistory-nav mr-auto">
    {{#each matchhistory}}
        <li class="nav-item" class="color-{{this.result}}">
            {{this.champion}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: I was trying to use EJS, but the thing that confuses me, is that It wont let me run a function that creates DOM elements inside the template because it is run server side and the DOM doesnt exist yet. So I dont know how im going to be able to create a number of DOM elements based on how many matches there are.